# Rails 3: Devise: No route matches "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm running into some issues when trying to add Devise to my Rails 3 app. I started by creating a new Rails 3 (rc2) app with a "Home" controller and "index" action and verified that "/" would render "#home/index". Next I set devise 1.1.1 in my Gemfile, installed Devise, created a User model, and migrated the database. Now "/" returns No route matches "/" and none of the Devise routes will work.

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the latest gem version (1.1.1) of Devise does not work with Rails 3.0.0rc2. You must use the latest version from github.

Modify your Gemfile from:

```
gem 'devise', '1.1.1'
```

To:

```
gem "devise", :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
```

Comment: For future Rails 3 projects, omit the `:git` part. Otherwise you will be using the HEAD version (master branch) of the gem instead of a stable release version.